# What are some good resources to learn Vector Spaces for Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations

I am currently using Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics. I had no trouble understanding finite dimension vector spaces using it. But I find it difficult to understand infinite dimensional vector spaces using this book. What are some alternative resources that I can use?

Comment: Try Debnath, Mikusinski - Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications (AP, 1990). My favorite book on math. methods of QM.

Comment: Is there something in particular which you're struggling with?  I ask because the subtleties of infinite dimensional vector spaces are often glossed over in physics books, so if you are concerned with technical issues then a more mathematical resource might help; on the other hand, if it's just the presentation of the material which you don't like, a different physics book might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first chapter of Shankar's Quantum Mechanics contains a thorough introduction on the linear algebra necessary. I have found out that learning linear algebra from a math textbook can be somewhat counterproductive- but I might be wrong.